# call a php function through javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ok, I am trying to test this jQuery. I want to run my other php file from ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var switchOn = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '../remote/test.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'text',
    data: {test: 'Hello there!'},
    success: function(data) {
      document.write(data);
    }

  });
}


//Button functions

function changeState1()
{
    if(window.document.myform.switch1[0].checked){
            window.document.myform.switch1[1].checked = true;
            document.myform.changeStateButton1.value = "Turn On";
            switchOn();

    }else{
            window.document.myform.switch1[0].checked = true;
            document.myform.changeStateButton1.value = "Turn Off";
        switchOn();

    }
}

function changeState2()
{
    if(window.document.myform.switch2[0].checked){
            window.document.myform.switch2[1].checked = true;
            document.myform.changeStateButton2.value = "Turn On";


    }else{
            window.document.myform.switch2[0].checked = true;
            document.myform.changeStateButton2.value = "Turn Off";

    }
}

function changeState3()
{
    if(window.document.myform.switch3[0].checked){
            window.document.myform.switch3[1].checked = true;
            document.myform.changeStateButton3.value = "Turn On";


    }else{
            window.document.myform.switch3[0].checked = true;
            document.myform.changeStateButton3.value = "Turn Off";

    }
}

function changeState4()
{
    if(window.document.myform.switch4[0].checked){
            window.document.myform.switch4[1].checked = true;
            document.myform.changeStateButton4.value = "Turn On";


    }else{
            window.document.myform.switch4[0].checked = true;
            document.myform.changeStateButton4.value = "Turn Off";

    }
}


</script>

<form name="myform" action="index.php?p=remotecontrol" method="POST">
<b>On/Off</b>
<br>
Switch 1
<br>
<input type="radio" name="switch1" onClick="window.document.myform.switch.value = 'On'">
<input type="radio" name="switch1" onClick="window.document.myform.switch.value = 'Off'">
<input type="button" id="changeStateButton1" name="changeStateButton1" value="Turn On" onClick="changeState1()">
<br>
Switch 2
<br>
<input type="radio" name="switch2" onClick="window.document.myform.switch.value = 'On'">
<input type="radio" name="switch2" onClick="window.document.myform.switch.value = 'Off'">
<input type="button" id="changeStateButton2" name="changeStateButton2" value="Turn On" onClick="changeState2()">
<br>
Switch 3
<br>
<input type="radio" name="switch3" onClick="window.document.myform.switch.value = 'On'">
<input type="radio" name="switch3" onClick="window.document.myform.switch.value = 'Off'">
<input type="button" id="changeStateButton3" name="changeStateButton3" value="Turn On" onClick="changeState3()">
<br>
Switch 4
<br>
<input type="radio" name="switch4" onClick="window.document.myform.switch.value = 'On'">
<input type="radio" name="switch4" onClick="window.document.myform.switch.value = 'Off'">
<input type="button" id="changeStateButton4" name="changeStateButton4" value="Turn On" onClick="changeState4()">
<br>

</form>
```

This is my other php file.

```
<?php
item1 = $_REQUEST['test'];

    echo $item1;


?>
```

I am sure that the code gets to the ajax function, but then there are nothing happening on my page. There are supposed to be an echo from the other php file. The test.php is in Sites/remote, which are the same directory the first file are. I have tried url '../test.php' and '../remote/test.php'. No differences...

Comment: *"but it doesn't work"* is a **useless** problem/error description. Please be specific about what happens and what you expect to happen. Some hints: Do you get any errors? On the JavaScript or PHP side? Is the Ajax request sent at all? Do you get a response?

Comment: What's the browser you use during test this code?

Comment: `exec('tdtool -n' . escapeshellarg($switch));`

Comment: @FelixKling Agreed. Please save us some time by explaining your problem instead of expecting us to work that out also.

Comment: I have no errors, it seems that my php file never are called

Comment: i changed the question to a more basic one, i think if i can make this work, i can get everything else to work.

Answer (score 0):

from the code you posted it seems that you have the PHP functions declared, but you never call them.

in your php file you should also have something similar to:

```
if (isset($_GET['switch']))
{
    $switch=$_GET['switch'];
    if ( "something" == $switch )
    {
        setSwitchOn($switch);
    }
    else
    {
        if ( "something else" == $switch )
        {
            setSwitchOff($switch)
        }
        else
        {
            // some other code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
callPage('setSwitch.php?switch='+targetSwitch ....

callPage('remote/setSwitch.php?switch='+tar ....
```

you have 2 setSwitch.php , 1 in remote and 1 in same folder

AND

```
switch='+targetSwitch,document.getElementById(targetId)
```

just pass targetId than how to know it off or on..maybe

```
switch='+targetSwitch,document.getElementById(targetId)+'&acrion=off'
```

AND

```
function callPage(url, div){ //need 2 var
```